# Expanding an accordion and scrolling to a section after expansion

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a comments section and a review form at the bottom of the comments section. I have the entire comments section wrapped in a Bootstrap Accordion with the class of Collapse:

### CODEPEN:

Check out the demo. Note clicking the "leave a review" link expands the `review_form`, but does not scroll to.
[Working codepen](https://codepen.io/Sackadelic/pen/QWyKXWK)

I've tried `onClick="window.scrollTo(#review_form)"`, but that does not work.

### Basic HTML:

```
<div class="review-collapse">
  <button class="woocommerce button review-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#commentList" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="commentList">SHOW ALL REVIEWS'</button>
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="commentList">
  
  <div class="leave-review">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#review_form_wrapper" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="review_form_wrapper" onClick="window.scrollTo(#review_form)">Leave a review?></a>
  </div>

    <ol class="commentList">
      //Comments here
    </ol>

<div id="review_form_wrapper" class="collapse">
  <div id="review_form">
    //review form to be expanded
  </div>
</div
```

I want to focus on the `a` in `.leave-review`: I would like to expand the `#review_form_wrapper` on click, and then scroll to the section immediately after. I can get the form to expand, but I cannot get the form to scroll into view.

Any suggestions?  I would like to use Vanilla JS if possible, but jQuery is fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by not using `window.scrollTo(#reviewForm)` but the `scrollIntoView()` method. I had to check if the `#review_form_wrapper` had the class of `show` before scrolling, which I used a `setTimeout()` for:

```
function productReviewJS() {
  const link = document.querySelector("#scrollToReview");
  link.addEventListener("click", function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      if (reviewForm.classList.contains("show")) {
        form.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
      }
    }, 400);
  });
}
productReviewJS();
```